# How to view/average a groupby dataframe when the data is a string?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset and I used pandas and groupby. I want to find the mean of a bunch of data based on certain criteria(countries). So I want the mean of these arrival_prices for each country(roughly 40). I used groupby, but I don't know how to access and/or find the mean of this data given it is in string format.

I've tried changing the excel file to change the datatype of arrival price to integers but it doesn't work. I don't know how to view the object.

```
       arrival_price  ... trading_group
    0                 0  ...          GLB8
    2                 0  ...          GLB8
    4                 0  ...          GLB8
    7              43.7  ...          GLB8
    12                0  ...          GLB8
    ...             ...  ...           ...
    30370             0  ...          GLB7
    30372             0  ...          GLB7
    30374             0  ...          GLB8
    30380        -16.95  ...          USA5
    30387             0  ...          GLB8
```

```py
x = df1.groupby('country', as_index = False)['arrival_price'].mean
```

This is what is shown in terminal:

```
bound method groupby.mean of pandas.core.groupby.generic.dataframegroupby object at 0x1173ce128

<bound method GroupBy.mean of <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x1173ce128>>
```

Only error is that arrival_price is a string, so I cannot take a mean(I have to convert it to a float or int first). I also don't know how to view the object.

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a pair of parenthesis at the end of the line to call the `mean` method:

```
x = df1.assign(arrival_price=df['arrival_price'].astype(float)).groupby('country', as_index = False)['arrival_price'].mean()
```

Comment: pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'astype' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: @EmilGeorgiev Try now